# Python MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.8 TiB for an array with shape () and data type int64

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine two data sets.
Using codes as follows

```
pd1=pd.read_csv('path1')  # 1456472 rows x 17 columns
pd2=pd.read_csv('path2')  # 1083899 rows x 42 columns
pd=pd.merge(left=pd1,right=pd2,how='left',on='id')
```

It returns with error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.8 TiB for an array with shape (1483050607760,) and data type int64

How can I solve this if my laptop is a 500GB+8GB one?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140446/merging-two-pandas-dataframes-with-many-sparse-columns-results-in-a-dataframe-th

Comment: try

`pd1=pd.read_csv('path1',chunksize=1000000)`

Comment: @venky__ : No but thanks. Columns in my data contain numbers and texts.

Comment: @sygneto then it returns a TextFileReader instead of a df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try dask then you can convert it to pandas if you want to on other machine

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

#pip install "dask[dataframe]"

dd1=dd.read_csv('path1') 
dd2=dd.read_csv('path2')  
dd=dd.merge(left=dd1,right=dd2,how='left',on='id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this new way to convert sparse matrix directly to dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(vectorized_text)
```